# The best way for get range of array

Tags: php

I have array for example with 9 keys:

```
<?php

$array = array(3,1,4,5,7,34,32,12,13);

print_r($array);
```

I would like get data from this array or remove others values.

For example:

```
$first = 2;
$last = 5;
```

this should return me:

```
$new_array = array(1,4,5,7);
```

how is the best method for this?

Comment: Can you be more specific in what you're looking for? Also a standard way of filtering an array is using the `array_filter` function.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the function [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice) for this:

```
$sub_array = array_slice($array, $first - 1, count($array) - $last);
```

Answer (score 3):

[`array_slice ( array $array , int $offset [, int $length = NULL [, bool $preserve_keys = false ]] )`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

Comment: You could probably put a little more in to this nominally correct answer.

Comment: w3schools has a good reference. [http://w3schools.com/php/func_array_slice.asp](http://w3schools.com/php/func_array_slice.asp)

Comment: ... why check out the reference on w3schools when the actual documentation on php.net is far more likely to be complete and accurate? The answer didn't need yet another link, especially not to a notoriously unreliable site like w3schools.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want to use is the [array_slice()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) function:

```
<?php
$input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");

$output = array_slice($input, 2);      // returns "c", "d", and "e"
$output = array_slice($input, -2, 1);  // returns "d"
$output = array_slice($input, 0, 3);   // returns "a", "b", and "c"

// note the differences in the array keys
print_r(array_slice($input, 2, -1));
print_r(array_slice($input, 2, -1, true));
?>
```

For your question:

```
<?php

$array = array(3,1,4,5,7,34,32,12,13);

$first = 2;
$last = 5;

$new_array = array_slice($array, $first - 1, $last - 1);
print_r($new_array);
// Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 4 [2] => 5 [3] => 7 ) 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [array_splice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php):

```
$array = array(3,1,4,5,7,34,32,12,13);
$first = 2;
$end = 5;
$length = ($end - $first);
$new_array = array_splice($array, $first, $end)
```